# Component displaying unexpected outputs

Tags: angular

I have been trying to display the data in html component but the problem i am facing is that when i go to the component after entering the first values it gets displayed correctly, the second time when i enter the values and retrieve them the first value is displayed correctly but second values get displayed 2 times, similarily the third time i enter the values and retrieve them the first value gets displayed 1 time, second value 2 times and third value gets displayed 3 times, sorry the problem or the explaination might be silly so here i am showing you the screen shot

https://ibb.co/19T90jf

Below is the code

component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Productservice } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-admin-products',
templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.scss']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
listofproducts
constructor(private prservice:Productservice,private 
router:Router,private route:ActivatedRoute) { 

}

ngOnInit() {
this.listofproducts=this.prservice.getallproducts()
console.log(this.listofproducts)

 }

}
```

another component

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Productservice } from 'src/app/services/products.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
selector: 'app-new-card',
templateUrl: './new-card.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./new-card.component.scss']
})
export class NewCardComponent implements OnInit {
subscription:Subscription
cardvalue
constructor(private 
prservice:Productservice,router:Router,route:ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.subscription=this.prservice.productcard.subscribe(
  (value)=>{
  this.cardvalue=value
  // console.log(this.cardvalue) 
  this.prservice.addtocardarray(this.cardvalue)

  }
 )

 }

  }
```

service file

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

export class Productservice{

productcard=new Subject<[]>()
cards=[]


addtocardarray(value){
this.cards.push(value)
// console.log(this.cards)
}

getallproducts(){
    return this.cards
}

}
```

Comment: not enough info given, where are you calling addtocardarray()?

Comment: @spfellers i updated it ,pls have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this line of code:

`this.prservice.productcard.subscribe((value) =>
    ...
    this.prservice.addtocardarray(this.cardvalue)
)`

you are subscribing to productcard in each of your new components without unsubscribing, meaning if you have 3 of these components and productcard emits a val, `addtocardarray(val)` is going to be called 3 times

you should add in a `.pipe(take(1))` before your subscription.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html

Comment: hey ya it worked !!!..just  a silly question....how do u come  to know about this (take) ? i was googling  but didnt find any solution